# How to get the latest Title of the employee once he or she gets promoted in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get the Title of the employee once he or she gets promoted.
I have the data of the employees logged the time in the timesheet that means I have the date with month in a sheet called the Main sheet. There is one helper sheet I have built that has the promotion details. Now I want to get these titles on the Main sheet.

Use Cases:

1. For instance, In the Main sheet, we have the data like this:
   Date       Name       Hours    Title
   2019-01   Max King    10        to get from Helper Sheet
   2019-02   Max King    20        to get from Helper Sheet
   2019-03   Max King    30        to get from Helper Sheet

Now in the Helper Sheet, I have this data
Date       Name       Title
2019-01   Max King    Trainee
2019-03   Max King    Senior

Now in the above scenario, I dont have 2019-02 date in the Helper sheet so that I can easily bring the Title. In the Main Sheet, Against 2019-02 I want to bring the title Trainee.

Can someone please guide me?

Thanks

Here is the link to data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hfXCFTp_vLqPFjazM-Vo6-3o8J1td1zpnCJOeK1LBg0/edit?usp=sharing

[Helper Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoMWl.png)

[Main Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEAcu.png)

Comment: Please have a look at the images for clarity.

Comment: Your sheet is locked. Please change the link permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: given you the access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula in C1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Title";IF(A2:A="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B,SORT(FILTER({Helper!B2:B&Helper!A2:A,Helper!D2:D},Helper!B2:B<>"")),2,TRUE),"NOT FOUND"))})`

This one formula produces the header and all results for C2:C.

You may change the header text within the formula as you like.

Essentially, the combined name-date is looked up within a sorted virtual array of the name-date and title from the "Helper" sheet, and the title (column 2 of that array) is returned if found. The final parameter of the `VLOOKUP` is `TRUE`, which means the search column is in strict sorted order and, if no exact match is found, to back up and grab the closest match before the searched one.